# Como modificar elementos del DOM

Tags: javascript, html

Llevo un par de horas intentando resolver esto sin resultado alguno.

**Mi objetivo es calcular la media de 3 números** obtenidos de un **"form"** insertadas mediante **"inputs"**  y enviar  este resultado a un **"td"**. Pero no consigo que se envíe el resultado.

Tabla del HTML

```
    <div id="tabla">
        <table id="list" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3" border="1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Nombre</td>
                    <td>Apellidos</td>
                    <td>Sexo</td>
                    <td>Nota 1</td>
                    <td> Nota 2</td>
                    <td>Nota 3</td>
                    <td id="display">Nota Media</td>
                    <td>Eliminar</td>

                </tr>

            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>

        </table>
    </div>
```

Button

```
      <p>
<button type="button" onclick="apply()" class="media" id="median"> Añadir</button>
 </p>
```

JS

```
    function Promedio() {
        var not1 = document.getElementById('not1').value;
        var not2 = document.getElementById('not2').value;
        var not3 = document.getElementById('not3').value;
        var display = document.getElementsByTagName('td')[7];innerHTML;
     var cal = (parseFloat(not1) + parseFloat(not2) + parseFloat(not3)) / 3;
        display.innerHTML = cal;
        

    }

    function TablaData() {

        var rows = "";
        var nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
        var apellidos = document.getElementById("apellidos").value;
        var Sexo = document.querySelector('input[name="Sexo"]:checked').value;
        var not1 = document.getElementById("not1").value;
        var not2 = document.getElementById("not2").value;
        var not3 = document.getElementById("not3").value;
        var display = document.getElementsByTagName("td")[6].innerHTML;
        rows += "<tr><td>" + nombre + "</td><td>" + apellidos + "</td><td>" + Sexo + "</td><td>" + not1 + "</td><td>" + not2 + "</td><td>" + not3 + "</td><td>" + display + "</td></tr>";
        $(rows).appendTo("#list tbody");

    }

    function apply() {
        TablaData();
        Promedio();
        
    }
</script>
```

Solo conisgo que en el td aparezca el texto : Nota Media o HTMLTableCellElement

Aquí el código: https://jsfiddle.net/wy9tseo7/

Comment: Copia el codigo en la pregunta mejor :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posible solución:

Deja la función `Promedio()` de este modo:

```javascript
function Promedio() {
  var not1 = document.getElementById('not1').value;
  var not2 = document.getElementById('not2').value;
  var not3 = document.getElementById('not3').value;
  var cal = (parseFloat(not1) + parseFloat(not2) + parseFloat(not3)) / 3;
  return cal;
}
```

Así te devolvera el valor promedio de las tres notas.

Y en la función `TablaData` cambia esto:

```javascript
var display = document.getElementsByTagName("td")[6].innerHTML;
```

por esto

```javascript
var display = Promedio();
```

Y en la función `apply` elimina la llamada a `Promedio()` y a `DeleteBtn()`;

Aquí te dejo un snippet funcionando con esos cambios:

```js
function Promedio() {
  var not1 = document.getElementById('not1').value;
  var not2 = document.getElementById('not2').value;
  var not3 = document.getElementById('not3').value;
  var cal = (parseFloat(not1) + parseFloat(not2) + parseFloat(not3)) / 3;
  return cal;
}

function TablaData() {
  var rows = "";
  var nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
  var apellidos = document.getElementById("apellidos").value;
  var Sexo = document.querySelector('input[name="Sexo"]:checked').value;
  var not1 = document.getElementById("not1").value;
  var not2 = document.getElementById("not2").value;
  var not3 = document.getElementById("not3").value;
  var display = Promedio();
  rows += "<tr><td>" + nombre + "</td><td>" + apellidos + "</td><td>" + Sexo + "</td><td>" + not1 + "</td><td>" + not2 + "</td><td>" + not3 + "</td><td>" + display + "</td></tr>";
  $(rows).appendTo("#list tbody");

}

function apply() {
  TablaData();
}
```

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport">
    <title> Registro </title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <form>
        <p>
          <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Ingrese nombre">
        </p>
        <input type="text" name="apellidos" id="apellidos" placeholder="Ingrese apellido">
        <div>
          <br><input type="radio" name="Sexo" value="Hombre" checked>
          Hombre
          <input type="radio" name="Sexo" value="Mujer">
          Mujer
        </div>
        <div>
          <br><label>Nota primer trismetre</label>
          <input type="number" class="notas" id="not1">
          <br><label>Nota segundo trimestre</label>
          <input type="number" class="notas" id="not2">
          <br><label>Nota tercer trimestre</label>
          <input type="number" class="notas" id="not3">
        </div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <p>
              <select name="curso" id="nombre" placeholder="Curso al que pertenece">
                <option value="1"> Primer curso</option>
                <option value="2"> Segundo curso</option>
              </select>
            </p>
          </div>

        </div>
        <p><button type="button" onclick="apply()" class="media" id="median"> Añadir</button>
        </p>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div id="data"></div>
    <div id="tabla">
      <table id="list" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3" border="1">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td>Nombre</td>
            <td>Apellidos</td>
            <td>Sexo</td>
            <td>Nota 1</td>
            <td> Nota 2</td>
            <td>Nota 3</td>
            <td id="display">Nota Media</td>
            <td id="Eliminar"><input type="button" width="100%" height="100%" name="Eliminar" onclick="DeleteBtn(d)" />Eliminar</td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

He borrado también la función `DeleteBtn` por ser irrelevante en esta pregunta y porque daba un error que no tenia que ver con ella.
Cuando la quieras usar aplica la misma lógica que ahora ves con `Promedio()`.

Por cierto, tienes el `id="nombre"` repetido en tu página y deberias coregirlo.

Comment: Funciona , entendí lo que faltaba . Muchas Gracias.